Playwright linking unrelated commands
I have the following piece of Playwright test:
(line 263)    expect(page.getByTestId("pode-dialog-title")).toBeVisible({ timeout: 10000, visible: true });
(line 269)    expect(page.locator('span').getByText(`Full name (${browserName})`, { exact: false })).toHaveCount(1);

              const select = page.locator(".svelte-select").first();
(line 274)    await select.dispatchEvent("pointerup", { timeout: 1000 });

The test fails with the error log indicating source of failure is line 274
but lines 263 and 269 are also reported as failed.
Please see screenshot.
What I don't get is the relationship between these commands. My expectation is that, these are independent checks.
And this only happens in Chrome and intermittently.



I missed 'await' before expect and so there were race conditions. Now the test fails correctly at line 263
